# How to find out and exclude an implicit dependency with Maven3?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat7, pom.xml, dependency-management

I have a `pom.xml` file with several dependencies, one of them being `c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar`. However, when deploying the webapp with Tomcat7, the `WEB-INF/lib` subdirectory contains two versions for the same dependency:

```
c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar
c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar
```

I want to exclude version `0.9.1.1`. I run:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

However, only version `0.9.5.1` appears, the other `jar` file is not listed here. I need to exclude that version because it's causing a library conflict and currently my ugly workaround is manually removing the `0.9.1.1` version via `rm` and restarting Tomcat7.

I also tried adding an `<exclude>` block on each dependency but the file is still placed in the `WEB-INF/lib` subdirectory of the Tomcat7 webapp subdirectory.

Maven version is 3.0.5-1.

How can I find out what dependency is generating that old version and how can I forcibly exclude it?

This is the full `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd ">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.login.cas</groupId>
    <artifactId>local-cas-management</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>4.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <warName>cas-management</warName>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
          <artifactId>cas-management-webapp</artifactId>
          <version>${cas.version}</version>
          <type>war</type>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
          <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
          <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>mysql</groupId>
          <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
          <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
          <artifactId>cas-server-support-jdbc</artifactId>
          <version>${cas.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
          <artifactId>cas-server-support-ldap</artifactId>
          <version>${cas.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
          <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
          <version>${xml.apis.version}</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
          <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
          <version>${c3p0.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <commons.dbcp.version>2.0</commons.dbcp.version>
        <cas.version>4.1.1</cas.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.10.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.6</mysql.connector.version>
        <xml.apis.version>1.4.01</xml.apis.version>
        <c3p0.version>0.9.5.1</c3p0.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>ja-sig</id>
        <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/ </url>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

This would be the associated `dependency:tree`. As you can see, there's no version `0.9.1.1`.

```
[INFO] com.login.cas:local-cas-management:war:4.1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.jasig.cas:cas-management-webapp:war:4.1.1:runtime
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.10.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.10.Final:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.jasig.cas:cas-server-support-jdbc:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jasig.cas:cas-server-core:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jasig.cas:cas-server-core-api:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jasig.inspektr:inspektr-audit:jar:1.2.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jasig.inspektr:inspektr-common:jar:1.2.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-annotation:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jasig.service.persondir:person-directory-impl:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:2.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- javax.xml.bind:jsr173_api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jasig.service.persondir:person-directory-api:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-jexl:commons-jexl:jar:1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.cache:cache-api:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jsr107.ri:cache-ri-impl:jar:1.0.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.0-SP4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor:jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Beta1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.bitbucket.b_c:jose4j:jar:0.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.web:javax.el:jar:2.2.6:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.3:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.3:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.3:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jcl:jar:2.3:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.jasig.inspektr:inspektr-aspects:jar:1.2.GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.jasig.cas:cas-server-support-ldap:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.webflow:spring-webflow:jar:2.4.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- opensymphony:ognl:jar:2.6.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.webflow:spring-binding:jar:2.4.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.webflow:spring-js:jar:2.4.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework.webflow:spring-js-resources:jar:2.4.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.ldaptive:ldaptive:jar:1.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO] +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] \- com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.5.1:compile
[INFO]    \- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.10:compile
```

Comment: Have you tried `mvn clean package` and see if the file is still in there?

Comment: @Jens yes, each time the app is built I wipe out any directory from the `webapps` Tomcat7 directory and `mvn clean package` is used always.

Comment: Can you show your complete pom.xml?

Comment: @Jens added, also added the `dependency:tree` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar</packagingExcludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: Although @Jeff-Morin's answer is the clean way and indeed should be performed, in my case this is not a piece of software that was programmed by me and honestly, I've already spent *a lot* of time configuring it and don't want to bother much more with it since it's not straightforward to configure, so this solution is adequate for me. After adding that line, it removed the `0.9.1.1` version. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to proceed in a clean way, I strongly suggest you use Eclipse to check your dependency hierarchy. The Maven integration plugin provides for `pom.xml` files a **Dependency Hierarchy** view that lets you view which dependencies refer to one another.

In this view, you can manually exclude a given artifact by right-clicking it and selecting **Exclude Maven Artifact...** from the context menu.

You will be shown a dialog asking where to place dependency exclusion. Usually you shouldn't have to change the selection. Click **OK** and the `<exclude>` element will be automatically placed into the `pom.xml` file for you. If you are comfortable with the modified `pom.xml` file, don't forget to save it before you rebuild your project.

Apart from adjusting your `pom.xml` file, run a `mvn clean package` command to make sure no stale dependencies remain in your `target` folder.